# Invalid bitcode version error after updating AFNetworking

Tags: objective-c, afnetworking, afnetworking-2, afnetworking-3

So I updated AFNetworking in my project from v2.0 to v3.1 but ever since that I am getting '**invalid bitcode version (Producer: '802.0.38.0_0' Reader: '800.0.42.1_0')'**. The archive was generated successfully multiple times in Xcode 8.2 before the library update but since the lib update I haven't been able to. Any suggestions as to how to fix this without disabling bitcode or reverting back to v2.1?

Answer (score 0):

The AFNetworking v3.1 may be compiled by higher Xcode version, bitcode version is also upgraded.

The proposed Solutions:
1. update your Xcode to higher version(Maybe the latest)
2. turn "Enable Bitcode" option of your project BuildSettings to "NO".